# ivy conflict resolution fails?

Tags: java, ivy

I'm having some ugly load issues with ivy. The source of this is loading xml-apis, where apparently someone decided it would be a good idea for version numbers to go [backwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840989/eclipse-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-w3c-dom-elementtraversal). The version I need is 1.4.01. Ivy reasonably ( but in this case incorrectly ) evicts this for 2.0 based on some other dependencies I have.

There's a way you can tell ivy to use a specific version, apparently. According to the [docs](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/conflict.html), as well as a typical example  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627100/a-way-to-control-dependencies-ranges-for-upstream-dependencies-using-ivy), the syntax looks like this:

```
<dependencies>
 ...
 <dependency ... />
 <dependency ... />
 <conflict org="..." module="..." rev="..." />
```

This fails for me- using ivy 2.4, I get the error

> "ivy:retrieve] [xml parsing: ivy.xml:49:55: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a:
>   Invalid content was found starting with element 'dependency'. One of
>   '{conflict}' is expected. in file:/project/ivy.xml"

In ivy 2.0 I get

> Invalid content was found starting with element 'conflict'. One of
>   '{dependency, exclude}' is expected. in file:/project/ivy.xml

According to the ivy docs, "conflict" was added in version 2.0. Anyone have any ideas about what might be going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found an answer, in case anyone else runs into this issue - 
At least in this case, the conflict tag works at the *end*, but not mixed in with the dependency elements - i.e.

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency ../>
  <dependency ../>
  <conflict />
  <dependency ../>  <- conflict fails with a dependency after it.
```

Additionally, this works in 2.4 but *not* in 2.0.

Comment: mucho gracias !